# Syntax error trying to import the smtplib module

Tags: python, smtplib

I'm new to python and currently trying to send emails with a python script.

My problem is that I'm getting a SyntaxError when I try to import the smtplib module to my code:

```
from email.headerregistry import Address
from email.message import EmailMessage
from smtplib
import os

#with open("liste.txt", "r") as body:
#    print(body.read())

email_address = os.getenv('GMAIL_ADDRESS', None)
email_password = os.getenv('GMAIL_APPLICATION_PASSWORD',None)

to_address = (
    Address(display_name = 'Test Name', username = 'testmail', domain = 'gmail.com'),
)

def create_email_message(from_address, to_address, subject, body):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['From'] = from_address
    msg['To'] = to_address
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg.set_content(body)
    return msg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    msg = create_email_message(
        from_address = email_address,
        to_address = to_address,
        subject = 'Shopping list',
        body = 'Test grocery',
    )

    with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', port = 587) as smtp_server:
        smtp_server.ehlo()
        smtp_server.starttls()
        smtp_server.login(email_address, email_password)
        smtp_server.send_message(msg)

    print('Email sent succesfully')
```

I've tried to search for answers to the problem on google, but without any luck.
I also tried to install smtplib through cmd, but found out, that it already is built in to python...

```
File "c:\Users\denni\OneDrive\Dokumenter\python\grocerylist.py", line 3
from smtplib
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import smtplib
```

Not `from` use `import`

If you are to use from, you have to put `import x` after it like you did above

Comment: Of course...
That's my bad, didn't notice such a simple and stupid typo - Thank you so much!

Comment: @denn4617 You can approve the answer so others can find the answer as well